# What is the best way to handle multiple NFTs of the same collection in ERC1155?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, erc-721, nft, erc-1155

I'm learning ERC1155, and I'm a bit confused.

This is OpenZeppelin's example of an ERC1155 Contract:

[image: Open Zeppelin ERC1155 Example]

**They state that Thor's Hammer is an NFT (because only 1 was minted), while Gold is Fungible.**

Therefore this example contains several Fungible Tokens:

- Gold
- Silver
- Sword
- Shield

And only one Non-Fungible Token:

- Thor's Hammer

**But what if I want my ERC1155 contract to have multiple Collections of Non-Fungible Tokens?**

For example, say I want to create a Football Game with:

- 2 types of Fungible Tokens:

  - Gold
  - Silver
- 4 Collections of NFTs:

  - Players
  - Coaches
  - Jerseys
  - Stadiums

Example code:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity 0.7.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/solc-0.7/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";

contract FootballGame is ERC1155 {
    
    address public admin;
    
    // Non-Fungibles
    uint8 public constant PLAYER = 1;
    uint8 public constant COACH = 2;
    uint8 public constant JERSEY = 3;
    uint8 public constant STADIUM = 4;
    
    // Fungibles
    uint8 public constant GOLD = 5;
    uint8 public constant SILVER = 6;
    
    constructor() ERC1155("https://example.json") {
        admin = msg.sender;
    }
    
    modifier onlyAdmin() {
        require(msg.sender == admin, "This operation is only for Admins");
        _;
    }
    
    function mintCoins(uint _coinId, uint _amount) onlyAdmin external {
        require(_coinId == GOLD || _coinId == SILVER, "Invalid Coin ID");
        _mint(msg.sender, _coinId, _amount, "");
    }
    
    function mintNFT(uint _tokenId) onlyAdmin external {
        require(_tokenId == PLAYER || _tokenId == COACH || _tokenId == JERSEY || _tokenId == STADIUM, "Invalid Token ID");
        _mint(msg.sender, _tokenId, 1, "");
    }
}
```

Is this right?

The constant variables are supposed to be IDs that represent each type of token, right? Or wrong?

For instance, if I want to create multiple Stadiums can I just mint multiple NFTs with the ID of the Stadium collection?

Or do I have to mint Stadium A with ID 22, Stadium B with ID 23, Stadium C with ID 24, and so on?

**For NFTs in ERC1155, is an ID for each NFT? Or is it for each Collection of NFTs?**

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that it looks like the latter, unique id for each NFT, regardless of grouping (eg stadium). But to have NFT-like grouping there are a couple of considerations:

The [nft example implementation](https://github.com/pixowl/thesandbox-contracts/blob/master/src/Asset/ERC1155ERC721.sol#L112) uses an IS_NFT bit for id's with single supplies. Notice that mint uses a packId.
Perhaps this can be done more simply for your use case, or you can just use the example code.

And, from the spec's [metadata section](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1155.md#erc-1155-metadata-uri-json-schema)...

> This JSON schema is loosely based on the "ERC721 Metadata JSON Schema", but includes optional formatting to allow for ID substitution by clients. If the string {id} exists in any JSON value, it MUST be replaced with the actual token ID, by all client software that follows this standard.

Which presumably is a cosmetic different to not have large, unwieldy id's.

Comment: So the solution would be to auto increment the tokenId every time I mint an NFT?

Comment: @AntónioGonçalves Yes! For example: if you are creating tokens of years, this collection cannot have two tokens with id 2021 or three tokens with id 1980.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is have a mapping that tracks which NFT belongs to like this:

```
mapping(uint256=> string) public nftsCollections;
//whenever you mint an nft require the admin to pass the collection name and  //add it to this collection
nftsCollections[id]=collectionName;
```