# Is that possible to "merge" multiple ERC721 from different collections?

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, nft

Let say I create four distinct ERC721 contracts:

- Mouth
- Nose
- Eyes
- Head

I want to create a last one contract for holders of each one in order to merge all their NFT.

If I'm holder of each collection and I have 1 Mouth, 1 Nose, 1 Eyes and 1 Head, I want to merge them on the last contract.

Can I deal with all these contracts on the same website ?

Which type of contract I need for the MergeContract ?

Furthermore, how I can know what my Mouth, Nose, Eyes or Head look like on the new contract ?

Sorry If it look basic, I'm newbie.

Answer (score 0):

First off, interesting idea!

I would look at ERC1155 as one potential contract standard for being able to manage [multiple NFTs](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98422/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-multiple-nfts-of-the-same-collection-in-erc1155?rq=1) in the way you are suggesting, which is basically to associate NFTs of a given property together.

I would need you to share a bit more about your idea to be able to provide more specific assistance. Offhand, it sounds like you could use ERC1155 to mint and manage multiple NFTs, each with a given property (nose, eyes, head, etc).

Here's a great [walkthrough of putting together an ERC1155](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/create-an-erc1155/4433)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll take a look on 1155. The only thing I need to clarify is that I would like to stagger the release of the first collections: for example I release the mouths in March, then the eyes in May, etc. So, I don't know if it's possible to mix several ERC721 from different contracts on the ERC1155?